# Have trouble with a function not running

Tags: javascript, function

I have been working on this rock, paper, scissor game the last two weeks. And have now become stuck on how to get the function that picks the winner to work. I used a console.log to check if the function `self.velgVinner = function()` even run, but so far nothing.

I'm empty for ideas.

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "Assignment09.js"></script>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Assignment09</h1>
    <p id="vinner"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var spiller1valg;
var spiller2valg;

function Spiller(oppgave, id){
    this.oppgave = oppgave;
    this.id = id;

    var spillerid = "spiller" + id;
    var feilId = "spiller" + id;
    var valg = "spiller" + id + "valg";

    this.input = document.createElement("input");
    this.spillerfeil = document.createElement("div");
    this.spiller = document.createElement("div");
    this.text1 = document.createElement("div");


    //this.vinneren = document.createElement("div");

    //self.spillervalg = document.createElement("div");
    var self = this;

    self.input.id = spillerid;
    self.spillerfeil.id = feilId;
    self.text1.id = valg;

    self.lagBrett = function(){
        console.log("lager brett");

        self.spiller.style.border = "solid 1px";
        self.text1.innerHTML = this.oppgave;       

        self.spiller.appendChild(this.input);
        self.spiller.appendChild(this.text1);
        self.spiller.appendChild(this.spillerfeil);
        document.body.appendChild(this.spiller);

        this.input.onkeyup = this.regnUt;
        console.log(id);
    }

    this.regnUt = function(){

        if (self.input.value == "stein" || self.input.value == "saks" || self.input.value == "papir" ||       self.input.value == "Stein" || self.input.value == "Saks" || self.input.value == "Papir"){

                console.log("Gyldig valg");
                self.spillerfeil.innerHTML = "Gyldig valg";
                self.text1.innerHTML = "Spiller har valgt " + self.input.value ;

                self.text1.style.color = "green";
                self.spillerfeil.style.color = "black";

                if (self.id == 1){
                    spiller1valg = self.input.value;
                    console.log("spiller 1 " + spiller1valg);
                }

                else if (self.id == 2){
                    spiller2valg = self.input.value; 
                    console.log("spiller 2 " + spiller2valg);
                }
            }

            else{
            console.log("Ugyldig valg");
            self.spillerfeil.innerHTML = "Ugyldig valg";
            self.spillerfeil.style.color = "red";
        }
    }

    self.velgVinner = function(){
        console.log("velgVinner kjørte");

        if(spiller1valg != "" && spiller2valg != ""){

            if (spiller1valg == "stein" && spiller2valg == "saks" 
                || spiller1valg == "Stein" && spiller2valg == "Saks" 
                || spiller1valg == "saks" && spiller2valg == "papir"
                || spiller1valg == "Saks" && spiller2valg == "Papir" 
                || spiller1valg == "papir" && spiller2valg == "stein"
                || spiller1valg == "Papir" && spiller2valg == "Stein"){

                    document.getElementById("vinner").innerHTML = "Spiller 1 vant";
                    console.log("Spiller 1 vant");  
                    window.alert("Spiller 1 vant");
            }

            /*var vinner = new Spiller("Spiller 1 vant");
            vinner.designVinnerText();*/

            if (spiller2valg == "stein" && spiller1valg == "saks" 
                || spiller2valg == "Stein" && spiller1valg == "Saks" 
                || spiller2valg == "saks" && spiller1valg == "papir"
                || spiller2valg == "Saks" && spiller1valg == "Papir" 
                || spiller2valg == "papir" && spiller1valg == "stein"
                || spiller2valg == "Papir" && spiller1valg == "Stein"){

                    document.getElementById("vinner").innerHTML = "Spiller 2 vant";
                    console.log("Spiller 2 vant");  
                    window.alert("Spiller 2 vant");

                    /*var vinner = new Spiller("Spiller 2 vant");
                    vinner.designVinnerText();*/
            }

            else if(spiller1valg == spiller2valg){
                    document.getElementById("vinner").innerHTML = "Uavgjort";
                    console.log("Uavgjort");    
                    window.alert("Uavgjort");
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function(){

    var spiller1 = new Spiller("Skriv stein, saks eller papir: ", 1);
    spiller1.lagBrett()

    var spiller2 = new Spiller("Skriv stein, saks eller papir: ", 2);
    spiller2.lagBrett();

    document.getElementById("vinner").style.color = "green";

}
```

Comment: You never called the function anywhere.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: The function is in function Spiller, which is being called on these:            var spiller1 = new Spiller("Skriv stein, saks eller papir: ", 1);
    spiller1.lagBrett()                        maybe if I have it as a function not in an other function and call it that way

Comment: @Zuflus You are declaring a function inside Spiller, you are not calling it. To call `velgVinner` you need to do something like `spiller1.velgVinner()`, basically call the function on an instance of `Spiller`. Although based on your comments it doesn't appear that function belongs inside Spiller in the first place.

Comment: okey, it's calling the function now. Only get the "it's a tie" (Uavgjort) though, as spiller1valg and spiller2valg is empty at the beginning. Which means it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/112jbcao/2/

You never called

```
self.velgVinner();
```

It's at line 63

Answer (score -2):

Just wrap the function in an IIFE: `self.velgVinner = function(){` will be `(function(){function body})();`

Comment: I didn't see you calling this function anywhere, so this is your problem. You can use it as an Immediately Invoked Function Expression, or just call it after the initialisation of the contructor.

Comment: That won't work. It will be called with the wrong value of `this`, which the function depends on.

Comment: Haha no, you're wrong, I had the impression that he has some binding inside the function, to `this` scope, but it doesnt, so it's ok as I said.